# How to post a file along with parameter to webapi method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, content-type, fiddler

I am new to `ASP.NET Web API`. I have a sample `FileUpload` web api (from some site) to upload files to the server. 
Following works fine for uploading a file.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FileUpload()
       {
           // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
           if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
           {
               throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
           }

           // Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form
           // data will be loaded.
           //string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
           string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
           CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
           List<string> files = new List<string>();

           try
           {
               // Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
               await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

               foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
               {
                   files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
               }

               // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
               return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
           }
           catch (System.Exception e)
           {
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
           }
       }
       // We implement MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to override the filename of File which
       // will be stored on server, or else the default name will be of the format like Body-
       // Part_{GUID}. In the following implementation we simply get the FileName from 
       // ContentDisposition Header of the Request Body.
       public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
       {
           public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

           public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
           {
               return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
           }
       }
```

But, I want to send a `parameter` called as `'token'` of type `string` to the following method using `[FromBody]` is it possible?

**Required:**

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FileUpload([FromBody] string token)
    {
    //somecode here
    }
```

So, basically can we send `multiple Content-Type` data to the web api? Please suggest. I am using `Fiddler` for testing webapi.

**Eg:**

*Request Body(json):*
{"token":"FV00VYAP"}

Comment: I've also had some troubles with this. What I ended up doing was base64 encoding the file to be uploaded in the client and then adding it as a property to my PostModel.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass extra content in through query string and then read it from your CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.

```
// Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
               await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Then you can use `provider.FormData` to read the extra values you passed along.

```
// Show all the key-value pairs.
        foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
            }
        }
```

See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-2 for more details.